# HTML5 Video onseeked event handling

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I am trying to sync controls for an HTML5 video player across browsers. Currently I have an event handler for the seeked event set up so that when one client moves to a different place in the video, the new time is emitted to all other clients (this is done via node and socket.io) and their players are updated to move to that time. The issue is that once a client's player is updated with a new time, *their* onseeked event handler triggers and emits the time to other clients, causing a feedback loop.

Is there any way to differentiate between a manual change in the video time by a user and a programmatic change in time from the script? I would like the onseek handler to only trigger for the former.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suspending event listeners](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885207/suspending-event-listeners)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to solve this would be to use a flag and set it to *programmatic* when socket.io sends you a new time, and check if the flag is set before propagating it back to the server.

Also you need to set the flag to false again after a while using `SetTimeout()` so manual changes would be propagated, as they should.